# How to HREF the INDEX

Tags: html, indexing, web, href

So I want to make my logo the href back to the homepage which would be something like this C:\Users\Nathan Connor\Desktop\web but I was thinking, when I upload it to a hosting website it wont be able to find C:\Users\Nathan Connor\Desktop\web lol.. so how would I href it or would I have to change it all once uploaded onto a hosting site, because I cant buy a host at the moment to host it right now.

Answer (score 1):

Href has two paths:

1.Absolute Path

2.Relative Path

Your `C:\Users\Nathan Connor\Desktop\web\index.html`
is Absolute Path.

You need **"Relative Path"**.

If your hosting site root is "mysite" and your index.html in "mysite" like this:

```
mysite/
├── index.html
└── other
    └── about.html
```

Then your href is:

`<a href="index.html">index</a>` .

If your index.html in "**mysite/index.html**" and your have a **about.html** in **"mysite/other/about.html"** , you want refference index.html  in "about.html" ,then your href will is (in about.html) :

`<a href="../index.html">index</a>` .

Thanks!